# is there a way to append leading zero's to an ordered number list? (01 or 001 as opposed to just 1)

Tags: html, css

by default when you use the `<ol>` tag to create an ordered list you get something like:

1.
.
.
10.
.
.
100

...but is there a way to change or style the format where it appends a certain number of leading zero's to the list? I want the numbers to all line up and my list will go into the hundreds so I would need 2 leading zero's for single digits, 1 leading zero for double digits, and none for triple digits:

001
.
.
010
.
.
100

I haven't created the list yet but I wanted to know before I start if there is a simple or easy way to do this? I only need this effect for ordered lists. Do not want it to be a universal effect.

Answer (score 49):

```
ol { 
    list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
}
```

Comment: thank you but what if my preference is to always display 3 digits. like if my list only contains 9 objects and i want to force 2 leading zeros? or if it had 1-99 items and i want to force 1-9 to have two and 10-99 to have one? is this possible? essentially any number between 1-999 should be formated 001-999.

Comment: Im not sure that 2 leading zeros can be done without JS, certainly not a pure CSS solution...

Comment: @khanvict If you want to always force 2 leading zeros, you add that extra 0 on `:before` pseudo-element. See http://jsfiddle.net/uqhxox7e/

Comment: On some browsers you can define your own @Counter-style to have multiple leading zeros

Answer (score 26):

Here's a CSS solution using [counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters):

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: items;
}
li {
  display: block;
  counter-increment: items;
}
li:before {
  content: "00" counter(items)". ";
}
li:nth-child(n+10):before {
  content: "0" counter(items)". ";
}
li:nth-child(n+100):before {
  content: counter(items)". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
  <li>Item 17</li>
  <li>Item 18</li>
  <li>Item 19</li>
  <li>Item 20</li>
  <li>Item 21</li>
  <li>Item 22</li>
  <li>Item 23</li>
  <li>Item 24</li>
  <li>Item 25</li>
  <li>Item 26</li>
  <li>Item 27</li>
  <li>Item 28</li>
  <li>Item 29</li>
  <li>Item 30</li>
  <li>Item 31</li>
  <li>Item 32</li>
  <li>Item 33</li>
  <li>Item 34</li>
  <li>Item 35</li>
  <li>Item 36</li>
  <li>Item 37</li>
  <li>Item 38</li>
  <li>Item 39</li>
  <li>Item 40</li>
  <li>Item 41</li>
  <li>Item 42</li>
  <li>Item 43</li>
  <li>Item 44</li>
  <li>Item 45</li>
  <li>Item 46</li>
  <li>Item 47</li>
  <li>Item 48</li>
  <li>Item 49</li>
  <li>Item 50</li>
  <li>Item 51</li>
  <li>Item 52</li>
  <li>Item 53</li>
  <li>Item 54</li>
  <li>Item 55</li>
  <li>Item 56</li>
  <li>Item 57</li>
  <li>Item 58</li>
  <li>Item 59</li>
  <li>Item 60</li>
  <li>Item 61</li>
  <li>Item 62</li>
  <li>Item 63</li>
  <li>Item 64</li>
  <li>Item 65</li>
  <li>Item 66</li>
  <li>Item 67</li>
  <li>Item 68</li>
  <li>Item 69</li>
  <li>Item 70</li>
  <li>Item 71</li>
  <li>Item 72</li>
  <li>Item 73</li>
  <li>Item 74</li>
  <li>Item 75</li>
  <li>Item 76</li>
  <li>Item 77</li>
  <li>Item 78</li>
  <li>Item 79</li>
  <li>Item 80</li>
  <li>Item 81</li>
  <li>Item 82</li>
  <li>Item 83</li>
  <li>Item 84</li>
  <li>Item 85</li>
  <li>Item 86</li>
  <li>Item 87</li>
  <li>Item 88</li>
  <li>Item 89</li>
  <li>Item 90</li>
  <li>Item 91</li>
  <li>Item 92</li>
  <li>Item 93</li>
  <li>Item 94</li>
  <li>Item 95</li>
  <li>Item 96</li>
  <li>Item 97</li>
  <li>Item 98</li>
  <li>Item 99</li>
  <li>Item 100</li>
  <li>Item 101</li>
  <li>Item 102</li>
  <li>Item 103</li>
  <li>Item 104</li>
  <li>Item 105</li>
  <li>Item 106</li>
  <li>Item 107</li>
  <li>Item 108</li>
  <li>Item 109</li>
  <li>Item 110</li>
  <li>Item 111</li>
  <li>Item 112</li>
  <li>Item 113</li>
  <li>Item 114</li>
  <li>Item 115</li>
  <li>Item 116</li>
  <li>Item 117</li>
  <li>Item 118</li>
  <li>Item 119</li>
  <li>Item 120</li>
  <li>Item 121</li>
  <li>Item 122</li>
  <li>Item 123</li>
  <li>Item 124</li>
  <li>Item 125</li>
  <li>Item 126</li>
  <li>Item 127</li>
  <li>Item 128</li>
  <li>Item 129</li>
  <li>Item 130</li>
  <li>Item 131</li>
  <li>Item 132</li>
  <li>Item 133</li>
  <li>Item 134</li>
  <li>Item 135</li>
  <li>Item 136</li>
  <li>Item 137</li>
  <li>Item 138</li>
  <li>Item 139</li>
  <li>Item 140</li>
  <li>Item 141</li>
  <li>Item 142</li>
  <li>Item 143</li>
  <li>Item 144</li>
  <li>Item 145</li>
  <li>Item 146</li>
  <li>Item 147</li>
  <li>Item 148</li>
  <li>Item 149</li>
  <li>Item 150</li>
  <li>Item 151</li>
  <li>Item 152</li>
  <li>Item 153</li>
  <li>Item 154</li>
  <li>Item 155</li>
  <li>Item 156</li>
  <li>Item 157</li>
  <li>Item 158</li>
  <li>Item 159</li>
  <li>Item 160</li>
  <li>Item 161</li>
  <li>Item 162</li>
  <li>Item 163</li>
  <li>Item 164</li>
  <li>Item 165</li>
  <li>Item 166</li>
  <li>Item 167</li>
  <li>Item 168</li>
  <li>Item 169</li>
  <li>Item 170</li>
  <li>Item 171</li>
  <li>Item 172</li>
  <li>Item 173</li>
  <li>Item 174</li>
  <li>Item 175</li>
  <li>Item 176</li>
  <li>Item 177</li>
  <li>Item 178</li>
  <li>Item 179</li>
  <li>Item 180</li>
  <li>Item 181</li>
  <li>Item 182</li>
  <li>Item 183</li>
  <li>Item 184</li>
  <li>Item 185</li>
  <li>Item 186</li>
  <li>Item 187</li>
  <li>Item 188</li>
  <li>Item 189</li>
  <li>Item 190</li>
  <li>Item 191</li>
  <li>Item 192</li>
  <li>Item 193</li>
  <li>Item 194</li>
  <li>Item 195</li>
  <li>Item 196</li>
  <li>Item 197</li>
  <li>Item 198</li>
  <li>Item 199</li>
  <li>Item 200</li>
  <li>Item 201</li>
  <li>Item 202</li>
  <li>Item 203</li>
  <li>Item 204</li>
  <li>Item 205</li>
  <li>Item 206</li>
  <li>Item 207</li>
  <li>Item 208</li>
  <li>Item 209</li>
  <li>Item 210</li>
  <li>Item 211</li>
  <li>Item 212</li>
  <li>Item 213</li>
  <li>Item 214</li>
  <li>Item 215</li>
  <li>Item 216</li>
  <li>Item 217</li>
  <li>Item 218</li>
  <li>Item 219</li>
  <li>Item 220</li>
  <li>Item 221</li>
  <li>Item 222</li>
  <li>Item 223</li>
  <li>Item 224</li>
  <li>Item 225</li>
  <li>Item 226</li>
  <li>Item 227</li>
  <li>Item 228</li>
  <li>Item 229</li>
  <li>Item 230</li>
  <li>Item 231</li>
  <li>Item 232</li>
  <li>Item 233</li>
  <li>Item 234</li>
  <li>Item 235</li>
  <li>Item 236</li>
  <li>Item 237</li>
  <li>Item 238</li>
  <li>Item 239</li>
  <li>Item 240</li>
  <li>Item 241</li>
  <li>Item 242</li>
  <li>Item 243</li>
  <li>Item 244</li>
  <li>Item 245</li>
  <li>Item 246</li>
  <li>Item 247</li>
  <li>Item 248</li>
  <li>Item 249</li>
  <li>Item 250</li>
  <li>Item 251</li>
  <li>Item 252</li>
  <li>Item 253</li>
  <li>Item 254</li>
  <li>Item 255</li>
  <li>Item 256</li>
  <li>Item 257</li>
  <li>Item 258</li>
  <li>Item 259</li>
  <li>Item 260</li>
  <li>Item 261</li>
  <li>Item 262</li>
  <li>Item 263</li>
  <li>Item 264</li>
  <li>Item 265</li>
  <li>Item 266</li>
  <li>Item 267</li>
  <li>Item 268</li>
  <li>Item 269</li>
  <li>Item 270</li>
  <li>Item 271</li>
  <li>Item 272</li>
  <li>Item 273</li>
  <li>Item 274</li>
  <li>Item 275</li>
  <li>Item 276</li>
  <li>Item 277</li>
  <li>Item 278</li>
  <li>Item 279</li>
  <li>Item 280</li>
  <li>Item 281</li>
  <li>Item 282</li>
  <li>Item 283</li>
  <li>Item 284</li>
  <li>Item 285</li>
  <li>Item 286</li>
  <li>Item 287</li>
  <li>Item 288</li>
  <li>Item 289</li>
  <li>Item 290</li>
  <li>Item 291</li>
  <li>Item 292</li>
  <li>Item 293</li>
  <li>Item 294</li>
  <li>Item 295</li>
  <li>Item 296</li>
  <li>Item 297</li>
  <li>Item 298</li>
  <li>Item 299</li>
  <li>Item 300</li>
  <li>Item 301</li>
  <li>Item 302</li>
  <li>Item 303</li>
  <li>Item 304</li>
  <li>Item 305</li>
  <li>Item 306</li>
  <li>Item 307</li>
  <li>Item 308</li>
  <li>Item 309</li>
  <li>Item 310</li>
  <li>Item 311</li>
  <li>Item 312</li>
  <li>Item 313</li>
  <li>Item 314</li>
  <li>Item 315</li>
  <li>Item 316</li>
  <li>Item 317</li>
  <li>Item 318</li>
  <li>Item 319</li>
  <li>Item 320</li>
  <li>Item 321</li>
  <li>Item 322</li>
  <li>Item 323</li>
  <li>Item 324</li>
  <li>Item 325</li>
  <li>Item 326</li>
  <li>Item 327</li>
  <li>Item 328</li>
  <li>Item 329</li>
  <li>Item 330</li>
  <li>Item 331</li>
  <li>Item 332</li>
  <li>Item 333</li>
  <li>Item 334</li>
  <li>Item 335</li>
  <li>Item 336</li>
  <li>Item 337</li>
  <li>Item 338</li>
  <li>Item 339</li>
  <li>Item 340</li>
  <li>Item 341</li>
  <li>Item 342</li>
  <li>Item 343</li>
  <li>Item 344</li>
  <li>Item 345</li>
  <li>Item 346</li>
  <li>Item 347</li>
  <li>Item 348</li>
  <li>Item 349</li>
  <li>Item 350</li>
  <li>Item 351</li>
  <li>Item 352</li>
  <li>Item 353</li>
  <li>Item 354</li>
  <li>Item 355</li>
  <li>Item 356</li>
  <li>Item 357</li>
  <li>Item 358</li>
  <li>Item 359</li>
  <li>Item 360</li>
  <li>Item 361</li>
  <li>Item 362</li>
  <li>Item 363</li>
  <li>Item 364</li>
  <li>Item 365</li>
  <li>Item 366</li>
  <li>Item 367</li>
  <li>Item 368</li>
  <li>Item 369</li>
  <li>Item 370</li>
  <li>Item 371</li>
  <li>Item 372</li>
  <li>Item 373</li>
  <li>Item 374</li>
  <li>Item 375</li>
  <li>Item 376</li>
  <li>Item 377</li>
  <li>Item 378</li>
  <li>Item 379</li>
  <li>Item 380</li>
  <li>Item 381</li>
  <li>Item 382</li>
  <li>Item 383</li>
  <li>Item 384</li>
  <li>Item 385</li>
  <li>Item 386</li>
  <li>Item 387</li>
  <li>Item 388</li>
  <li>Item 389</li>
  <li>Item 390</li>
  <li>Item 391</li>
  <li>Item 392</li>
  <li>Item 393</li>
  <li>Item 394</li>
  <li>Item 395</li>
  <li>Item 396</li>
  <li>Item 397</li>
  <li>Item 398</li>
  <li>Item 399</li>
  <li>Item 400</li>
  <li>Item 401</li>
  <li>Item 402</li>
  <li>Item 403</li>
  <li>Item 404</li>
  <li>Item 405</li>
  <li>Item 406</li>
  <li>Item 407</li>
  <li>Item 408</li>
  <li>Item 409</li>
  <li>Item 410</li>
  <li>Item 411</li>
  <li>Item 412</li>
  <li>Item 413</li>
  <li>Item 414</li>
  <li>Item 415</li>
  <li>Item 416</li>
  <li>Item 417</li>
  <li>Item 418</li>
  <li>Item 419</li>
  <li>Item 420</li>
  <li>Item 421</li>
  <li>Item 422</li>
  <li>Item 423</li>
  <li>Item 424</li>
  <li>Item 425</li>
  <li>Item 426</li>
  <li>Item 427</li>
  <li>Item 428</li>
  <li>Item 429</li>
  <li>Item 430</li>
  <li>Item 431</li>
  <li>Item 432</li>
  <li>Item 433</li>
  <li>Item 434</li>
  <li>Item 435</li>
  <li>Item 436</li>
  <li>Item 437</li>
  <li>Item 438</li>
  <li>Item 439</li>
  <li>Item 440</li>
  <li>Item 441</li>
  <li>Item 442</li>
  <li>Item 443</li>
  <li>Item 444</li>
  <li>Item 445</li>
  <li>Item 446</li>
  <li>Item 447</li>
  <li>Item 448</li>
  <li>Item 449</li>
  <li>Item 450</li>
  <li>Item 451</li>
  <li>Item 452</li>
  <li>Item 453</li>
  <li>Item 454</li>
  <li>Item 455</li>
  <li>Item 456</li>
  <li>Item 457</li>
  <li>Item 458</li>
  <li>Item 459</li>
  <li>Item 460</li>
  <li>Item 461</li>
  <li>Item 462</li>
  <li>Item 463</li>
  <li>Item 464</li>
  <li>Item 465</li>
  <li>Item 466</li>
  <li>Item 467</li>
  <li>Item 468</li>
  <li>Item 469</li>
  <li>Item 470</li>
  <li>Item 471</li>
  <li>Item 472</li>
  <li>Item 473</li>
  <li>Item 474</li>
  <li>Item 475</li>
  <li>Item 476</li>
  <li>Item 477</li>
  <li>Item 478</li>
  <li>Item 479</li>
  <li>Item 480</li>
  <li>Item 481</li>
  <li>Item 482</li>
  <li>Item 483</li>
  <li>Item 484</li>
  <li>Item 485</li>
  <li>Item 486</li>
  <li>Item 487</li>
  <li>Item 488</li>
  <li>Item 489</li>
  <li>Item 490</li>
  <li>Item 491</li>
  <li>Item 492</li>
  <li>Item 493</li>
  <li>Item 494</li>
  <li>Item 495</li>
  <li>Item 496</li>
  <li>Item 497</li>
  <li>Item 498</li>
  <li>Item 499</li>
  <li>Item 500</li>
  <li>Item 501</li>
  <li>Item 502</li>
  <li>Item 503</li>
  <li>Item 504</li>
  <li>Item 505</li>
  <li>Item 506</li>
  <li>Item 507</li>
  <li>Item 508</li>
  <li>Item 509</li>
  <li>Item 510</li>
  <li>Item 511</li>
  <li>Item 512</li>
  <li>Item 513</li>
  <li>Item 514</li>
  <li>Item 515</li>
  <li>Item 516</li>
  <li>Item 517</li>
  <li>Item 518</li>
  <li>Item 519</li>
  <li>Item 520</li>
  <li>Item 521</li>
  <li>Item 522</li>
  <li>Item 523</li>
  <li>Item 524</li>
  <li>Item 525</li>
  <li>Item 526</li>
  <li>Item 527</li>
  <li>Item 528</li>
  <li>Item 529</li>
  <li>Item 530</li>
  <li>Item 531</li>
  <li>Item 532</li>
  <li>Item 533</li>
  <li>Item 534</li>
  <li>Item 535</li>
  <li>Item 536</li>
  <li>Item 537</li>
  <li>Item 538</li>
  <li>Item 539</li>
  <li>Item 540</li>
  <li>Item 541</li>
  <li>Item 542</li>
  <li>Item 543</li>
  <li>Item 544</li>
  <li>Item 545</li>
  <li>Item 546</li>
  <li>Item 547</li>
  <li>Item 548</li>
  <li>Item 549</li>
  <li>Item 550</li>
  <li>Item 551</li>
  <li>Item 552</li>
  <li>Item 553</li>
  <li>Item 554</li>
  <li>Item 555</li>
  <li>Item 556</li>
  <li>Item 557</li>
  <li>Item 558</li>
  <li>Item 559</li>
  <li>Item 560</li>
  <li>Item 561</li>
  <li>Item 562</li>
  <li>Item 563</li>
  <li>Item 564</li>
  <li>Item 565</li>
  <li>Item 566</li>
  <li>Item 567</li>
  <li>Item 568</li>
  <li>Item 569</li>
  <li>Item 570</li>
  <li>Item 571</li>
  <li>Item 572</li>
  <li>Item 573</li>
  <li>Item 574</li>
  <li>Item 575</li>
  <li>Item 576</li>
  <li>Item 577</li>
  <li>Item 578</li>
  <li>Item 579</li>
  <li>Item 580</li>
  <li>Item 581</li>
  <li>Item 582</li>
  <li>Item 583</li>
  <li>Item 584</li>
  <li>Item 585</li>
  <li>Item 586</li>
  <li>Item 587</li>
  <li>Item 588</li>
  <li>Item 589</li>
  <li>Item 590</li>
  <li>Item 591</li>
  <li>Item 592</li>
  <li>Item 593</li>
  <li>Item 594</li>
  <li>Item 595</li>
  <li>Item 596</li>
  <li>Item 597</li>
  <li>Item 598</li>
  <li>Item 599</li>
  <li>Item 600</li>
  <li>Item 601</li>
  <li>Item 602</li>
  <li>Item 603</li>
  <li>Item 604</li>
  <li>Item 605</li>
  <li>Item 606</li>
  <li>Item 607</li>
  <li>Item 608</li>
  <li>Item 609</li>
  <li>Item 610</li>
  <li>Item 611</li>
  <li>Item 612</li>
  <li>Item 613</li>
  <li>Item 614</li>
  <li>Item 615</li>
  <li>Item 616</li>
  <li>Item 617</li>
  <li>Item 618</li>
  <li>Item 619</li>
  <li>Item 620</li>
  <li>Item 621</li>
  <li>Item 622</li>
  <li>Item 623</li>
  <li>Item 624</li>
  <li>Item 625</li>
  <li>Item 626</li>
  <li>Item 627</li>
  <li>Item 628</li>
  <li>Item 629</li>
  <li>Item 630</li>
  <li>Item 631</li>
  <li>Item 632</li>
  <li>Item 633</li>
  <li>Item 634</li>
  <li>Item 635</li>
  <li>Item 636</li>
  <li>Item 637</li>
  <li>Item 638</li>
  <li>Item 639</li>
  <li>Item 640</li>
  <li>Item 641</li>
  <li>Item 642</li>
  <li>Item 643</li>
  <li>Item 644</li>
  <li>Item 645</li>
  <li>Item 646</li>
  <li>Item 647</li>
  <li>Item 648</li>
  <li>Item 649</li>
  <li>Item 650</li>
  <li>Item 651</li>
  <li>Item 652</li>
  <li>Item 653</li>
  <li>Item 654</li>
  <li>Item 655</li>
  <li>Item 656</li>
  <li>Item 657</li>
  <li>Item 658</li>
  <li>Item 659</li>
  <li>Item 660</li>
  <li>Item 661</li>
  <li>Item 662</li>
  <li>Item 663</li>
  <li>Item 664</li>
  <li>Item 665</li>
  <li>Item 666</li>
  <li>Item 667</li>
  <li>Item 668</li>
  <li>Item 669</li>
  <li>Item 670</li>
  <li>Item 671</li>
  <li>Item 672</li>
  <li>Item 673</li>
  <li>Item 674</li>
  <li>Item 675</li>
  <li>Item 676</li>
  <li>Item 677</li>
  <li>Item 678</li>
  <li>Item 679</li>
  <li>Item 680</li>
  <li>Item 681</li>
  <li>Item 682</li>
  <li>Item 683</li>
  <li>Item 684</li>
  <li>Item 685</li>
  <li>Item 686</li>
  <li>Item 687</li>
  <li>Item 688</li>
  <li>Item 689</li>
  <li>Item 690</li>
  <li>Item 691</li>
  <li>Item 692</li>
  <li>Item 693</li>
  <li>Item 694</li>
  <li>Item 695</li>
  <li>Item 696</li>
  <li>Item 697</li>
  <li>Item 698</li>
  <li>Item 699</li>
  <li>Item 700</li>
  <li>Item 701</li>
  <li>Item 702</li>
  <li>Item 703</li>
  <li>Item 704</li>
  <li>Item 705</li>
  <li>Item 706</li>
  <li>Item 707</li>
  <li>Item 708</li>
  <li>Item 709</li>
  <li>Item 710</li>
  <li>Item 711</li>
  <li>Item 712</li>
  <li>Item 713</li>
  <li>Item 714</li>
  <li>Item 715</li>
  <li>Item 716</li>
  <li>Item 717</li>
  <li>Item 718</li>
  <li>Item 719</li>
  <li>Item 720</li>
  <li>Item 721</li>
  <li>Item 722</li>
  <li>Item 723</li>
  <li>Item 724</li>
  <li>Item 725</li>
  <li>Item 726</li>
  <li>Item 727</li>
  <li>Item 728</li>
  <li>Item 729</li>
  <li>Item 730</li>
  <li>Item 731</li>
  <li>Item 732</li>
  <li>Item 733</li>
  <li>Item 734</li>
  <li>Item 735</li>
  <li>Item 736</li>
  <li>Item 737</li>
  <li>Item 738</li>
  <li>Item 739</li>
  <li>Item 740</li>
  <li>Item 741</li>
  <li>Item 742</li>
  <li>Item 743</li>
  <li>Item 744</li>
  <li>Item 745</li>
  <li>Item 746</li>
  <li>Item 747</li>
  <li>Item 748</li>
  <li>Item 749</li>
  <li>Item 750</li>
  <li>Item 751</li>
  <li>Item 752</li>
  <li>Item 753</li>
  <li>Item 754</li>
  <li>Item 755</li>
  <li>Item 756</li>
  <li>Item 757</li>
  <li>Item 758</li>
  <li>Item 759</li>
  <li>Item 760</li>
  <li>Item 761</li>
  <li>Item 762</li>
  <li>Item 763</li>
  <li>Item 764</li>
  <li>Item 765</li>
  <li>Item 766</li>
  <li>Item 767</li>
  <li>Item 768</li>
  <li>Item 769</li>
  <li>Item 770</li>
  <li>Item 771</li>
  <li>Item 772</li>
  <li>Item 773</li>
  <li>Item 774</li>
  <li>Item 775</li>
  <li>Item 776</li>
  <li>Item 777</li>
  <li>Item 778</li>
  <li>Item 779</li>
  <li>Item 780</li>
  <li>Item 781</li>
  <li>Item 782</li>
  <li>Item 783</li>
  <li>Item 784</li>
  <li>Item 785</li>
  <li>Item 786</li>
  <li>Item 787</li>
  <li>Item 788</li>
  <li>Item 789</li>
  <li>Item 790</li>
  <li>Item 791</li>
  <li>Item 792</li>
  <li>Item 793</li>
  <li>Item 794</li>
  <li>Item 795</li>
  <li>Item 796</li>
  <li>Item 797</li>
  <li>Item 798</li>
  <li>Item 799</li>
  <li>Item 800</li>
  <li>Item 801</li>
  <li>Item 802</li>
  <li>Item 803</li>
  <li>Item 804</li>
  <li>Item 805</li>
  <li>Item 806</li>
  <li>Item 807</li>
  <li>Item 808</li>
  <li>Item 809</li>
  <li>Item 810</li>
  <li>Item 811</li>
  <li>Item 812</li>
  <li>Item 813</li>
  <li>Item 814</li>
  <li>Item 815</li>
  <li>Item 816</li>
  <li>Item 817</li>
  <li>Item 818</li>
  <li>Item 819</li>
  <li>Item 820</li>
  <li>Item 821</li>
  <li>Item 822</li>
  <li>Item 823</li>
  <li>Item 824</li>
  <li>Item 825</li>
  <li>Item 826</li>
  <li>Item 827</li>
  <li>Item 828</li>
  <li>Item 829</li>
  <li>Item 830</li>
  <li>Item 831</li>
  <li>Item 832</li>
  <li>Item 833</li>
  <li>Item 834</li>
  <li>Item 835</li>
  <li>Item 836</li>
  <li>Item 837</li>
  <li>Item 838</li>
  <li>Item 839</li>
  <li>Item 840</li>
  <li>Item 841</li>
  <li>Item 842</li>
  <li>Item 843</li>
  <li>Item 844</li>
  <li>Item 845</li>
  <li>Item 846</li>
  <li>Item 847</li>
  <li>Item 848</li>
  <li>Item 849</li>
  <li>Item 850</li>
  <li>Item 851</li>
  <li>Item 852</li>
  <li>Item 853</li>
  <li>Item 854</li>
  <li>Item 855</li>
  <li>Item 856</li>
  <li>Item 857</li>
  <li>Item 858</li>
  <li>Item 859</li>
  <li>Item 860</li>
  <li>Item 861</li>
  <li>Item 862</li>
  <li>Item 863</li>
  <li>Item 864</li>
  <li>Item 865</li>
  <li>Item 866</li>
  <li>Item 867</li>
  <li>Item 868</li>
  <li>Item 869</li>
  <li>Item 870</li>
  <li>Item 871</li>
  <li>Item 872</li>
  <li>Item 873</li>
  <li>Item 874</li>
  <li>Item 875</li>
  <li>Item 876</li>
  <li>Item 877</li>
  <li>Item 878</li>
  <li>Item 879</li>
  <li>Item 880</li>
  <li>Item 881</li>
  <li>Item 882</li>
  <li>Item 883</li>
  <li>Item 884</li>
  <li>Item 885</li>
  <li>Item 886</li>
  <li>Item 887</li>
  <li>Item 888</li>
  <li>Item 889</li>
  <li>Item 890</li>
  <li>Item 891</li>
  <li>Item 892</li>
  <li>Item 893</li>
  <li>Item 894</li>
  <li>Item 895</li>
  <li>Item 896</li>
  <li>Item 897</li>
  <li>Item 898</li>
  <li>Item 899</li>
  <li>Item 900</li>
  <li>Item 901</li>
  <li>Item 902</li>
  <li>Item 903</li>
  <li>Item 904</li>
  <li>Item 905</li>
  <li>Item 906</li>
  <li>Item 907</li>
  <li>Item 908</li>
  <li>Item 909</li>
  <li>Item 910</li>
  <li>Item 911</li>
  <li>Item 912</li>
  <li>Item 913</li>
  <li>Item 914</li>
  <li>Item 915</li>
  <li>Item 916</li>
  <li>Item 917</li>
  <li>Item 918</li>
  <li>Item 919</li>
  <li>Item 920</li>
  <li>Item 921</li>
  <li>Item 922</li>
  <li>Item 923</li>
  <li>Item 924</li>
  <li>Item 925</li>
  <li>Item 926</li>
  <li>Item 927</li>
  <li>Item 928</li>
  <li>Item 929</li>
  <li>Item 930</li>
  <li>Item 931</li>
  <li>Item 932</li>
  <li>Item 933</li>
  <li>Item 934</li>
  <li>Item 935</li>
  <li>Item 936</li>
  <li>Item 937</li>
  <li>Item 938</li>
  <li>Item 939</li>
  <li>Item 940</li>
  <li>Item 941</li>
  <li>Item 942</li>
  <li>Item 943</li>
  <li>Item 944</li>
  <li>Item 945</li>
  <li>Item 946</li>
  <li>Item 947</li>
  <li>Item 948</li>
  <li>Item 949</li>
  <li>Item 950</li>
  <li>Item 951</li>
  <li>Item 952</li>
  <li>Item 953</li>
  <li>Item 954</li>
  <li>Item 955</li>
  <li>Item 956</li>
  <li>Item 957</li>
  <li>Item 958</li>
  <li>Item 959</li>
  <li>Item 960</li>
  <li>Item 961</li>
  <li>Item 962</li>
  <li>Item 963</li>
  <li>Item 964</li>
  <li>Item 965</li>
  <li>Item 966</li>
  <li>Item 967</li>
  <li>Item 968</li>
  <li>Item 969</li>
  <li>Item 970</li>
  <li>Item 971</li>
  <li>Item 972</li>
  <li>Item 973</li>
  <li>Item 974</li>
  <li>Item 975</li>
  <li>Item 976</li>
  <li>Item 977</li>
  <li>Item 978</li>
  <li>Item 979</li>
  <li>Item 980</li>
  <li>Item 981</li>
  <li>Item 982</li>
  <li>Item 983</li>
  <li>Item 984</li>
  <li>Item 985</li>
  <li>Item 986</li>
  <li>Item 987</li>
  <li>Item 988</li>
  <li>Item 989</li>
  <li>Item 990</li>
  <li>Item 991</li>
  <li>Item 992</li>
  <li>Item 993</li>
  <li>Item 994</li>
  <li>Item 995</li>
  <li>Item 996</li>
  <li>Item 997</li>
  <li>Item 998</li>
  <li>Item 999</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is a great solution! However, it breaks for me when there’s one or more items that need to be skipped from the counting.

Comment: I fixed my problem by targeting only the first 10 items:       `li:nth-child(-n+10)::before { content: "00" counter(items)". "; }`. This way it seems to take into account any skipped items.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use JavaScript for this.

```
function addzeros(number, length) {
    var num = '' + number;
    while (num.length < length) {
        num = '0' + num;
    }
    return num;
}

alert(addzeros(100, 5))
```

**Example usage**
`addzeros(1,3)` will give you 001 
`addzeros(10,3)` will give you 010 
`addzeros(100,0)` will give you 100 
`addzeros(100,6)` will give you 000100

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ED8Hj/

Answer (score 2):

This can be done, depending on the browser. (Experimental api)

```
    @counter-style pad-3 {
        system: numeric;
        symbols: "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9";
        pad: 3 "0";
    }                                                 
    ol { 
      list-style-type: pad-3;           
     }
```

Comment: seems to be best solution

Comment: note: @counter-style is very modern API, see https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style for compatibility table.